# React-router v6 showing two routes at the same time

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have this code right here and i was following the react-router v6 example, but in the code below the `routes` is rendering two `route`(the `<Dashboard/>` and the Hello page on App start).

```
<Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<div><Outlet/></div>}>
          <Route index element={<div>hello</div>}/>
          <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
          <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
```

It works fine when i go to localhost/dashboard and localhost/login, but i want it to render the hello screen when it starts meaning at 'localhost/'. And why can't my code work?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Question is unclear. Are you asking how to display both the index route with "hello" ***and*** the `"/dashboard"` route at the same time? Or are you asking how to render 3 separate routes? It sounds like you want the latter, and that's what the code does. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v6-showing-two-routes-at-the-same-time-c5m0b2 Can you clarify the issue?

Comment: Your code works, I accidentally left another "<Dashboard/>" component under "<Routes/>. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I left another `<Dashboard/>` component under '`<Routes/>`' that was why it was showing duplicates.